# Show onscreen keyboard in Electron Kiosk Mode

Tags: ubuntu, electron, kiosk-mode

I'm developing an application using Electron in **Kiosk mode**.
The application is going to run on **Ubuntu touch screens**.

The problem is that when the user touch on a textfield the Ubuntu touch keyboard is displayed **under** the Electron App, so the user can't type nothing.

Is there a way to let the keyboard stay above the Electron app?

Thanks a lot

Comment: So basically you want the keyboard to stay on top of all the other apps (not just the electron app)?

Comment: Exactly. But the most important thing is that the keyboard stay on top of Electron in Kiosk mode

Comment: @Packa reference

Answer (score 0):

Not much information is given about the keyboard itself (I am assuming the keyboard is a child window running parallel to your parent window).

When you load the window(s) from the main process (main.js most likely), you have a bunch of settings you can apply to the window. In the **BrowserWindow**, you can add settings to your window by passing arguments like so:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

      function createKeyboard () {   // I am assuming you create the keyboard like so:
      const win = new BrowserWindow({
          //custom windows settings goes here e.g width:100 etc
          alwaysOnTop: true //this keeps the window on top of the screen at all times
        }
      })
    win.show();
      win.loadFile('src/index.html');
    }
```

By doing this, you can make it so your keyboard window is always on top of all the other apps and the Electron App. This has only been tested on windows 10, but it should work the same for Linux. Please let me know if this code is different to the code you used and I will try to update the question.

For more information, please see this [website](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window).